# Messages/redirect between Angular App and other site

Tags: angular, webview

I've got an Angular 14 app running on desktop and mobile browsers.
In a particular flow, I need to make a redirect to another website (which is on another server and not in my scope). After some operations, this site will give back the control to my Angular app.
I can suggest to the other site a way to communicate, so which could be the best way to implement this kind of interaction?

Thanks.

I thought that maybe the site could open my Angular app on a particular routing passing some parameters in request, but they are personal data so is there a way to make it safer?

Comment: Depending on how you open it, you could try postMessages https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thanks, I thought about postmessage but it requires a popup or an iframe, while the customer needs a redirect

Comment: If you are opening in a new tab, post message also works. If that doesn't work you would need some sort of api or websocket to communicate the data.